# React load variables from config file

Tags: reactjs, frontend, config, web-frontend

I'm now to FrontEnd-Development with React.

To make sure having the maximum flexibility, I want to load some variables from a specific CustomConfigFile.

This file should be generated if it's not found and can be loaded and edited on the UI.

Can somebody tell me whether this is possible at all and give me an example?

Comment: How do you want to generate the file? Is it coming from any API or anything else?

Comment: Actually, i thought I could just use a demo-file and copy and rename  it to the right place and the right name in case its missing...

Answer (score 1):

There are three steps you need to do:

1. If you want to achieve something like that, you need to store those values either in a database or a file in the server, you can use JSON, XML or whatever format you want.
2. Your client needs to load this file at runtime, you can use `fetch` for this.
3. Now, for the editing part. You are going to need an endpoint you can call from your client, that is able to update those values in the database or in the file. You can use node.js, PHP, ruby or whatever backend language you are comfortable with.

That's the logic you need to implement, I've done it with React + Laravel + MySQL  for this app: https://bleext.com/music people can change title, logo, language, the main menu, templates, and so many other things to customize the system.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

At the moment I just need 7 Variables so I would prefer the "file in the server" and JSON as a format

What do you mean by `fetch`? Is this file supplied over HTTP/S or over the filesystem?

My Demo-Data are supplied by a simple SpringBoot REST-API, can I use it for that purpose too?

Comment: you will have to load that file over the network using fetch like this: `fetch('https://yourdomain.com/config/env.json')`. Given that users can edit the value, you can't use the file system at build time, but rather use your server to handle the values and provide the data to the clients at run time.

Comment: Okay, I understand.
But how to realize the write back to file after editing?
And how to keep that file "secure"?

Comment: It depends on the language of your preference, you need to implement some sort of user authentication where only logged in user with the right permissions can access the endpoint that writes the file with the new values